# Is there a term historians use for an unknown person?

Tags: historiography

History documentaries (especially about the ancient past) often use representative actors to illustrate the narration. This usually happens when describing events where the participant's names are unknown. If someone wanted to use this method in a written work, they could use a phrase like “for example, humans...” and generalize.  But is there a more specific term that historians use?

Examples: Ancient human remains are given names such as [Ötzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96tzi) because the human's real name is unknown. Similar cases are "Pete Marsh" in lieu of "[Lindow Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindow_Man)" and "Ginger" referring to one of the [Gebelein mummies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebelein_predynastic_mummies).

A second example is the use of ["Nomen Nescio"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomen_nescio) which is similar to the English use of "John Doe."

A third example is shown in this excerpt from *Canaan and Israel in Antiquity: A Textbook on History and Religion* by K. L. Noll.

[image: book-excerpt]

In summary, what phrase would describe unknown persons, either when the real name is unknown or their existence is unrecorded? Based on what I've looked at so far, a term used in the study of [Counterfactual history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_history) could be relevant.

To be extra clear and to avoid discussion, this is not asking what the ‘best’ or ‘ideal’ term would be, only whether such a term exists or not.

Comment: “Creative-historyname” perhaps?

Comment: Historians don’t create characters like that. They rely on actual characters from the documentary record. Or they talk about classes or functions of people (the workers in Labour villages; carpenters in the mid North); or talk about processes (King Ludd’s men, the mobility as riot in London).

Comment: Writers of TV documentaries use characters like that to personalize the impact of the historical facts they want to tell. I see it as part of *science journalism*, not as part of the *science* the journalists talk about.

Comment: Additionally, for people who've done a 4 year degree in history, notice that I didn't say historians don't create characters.  The "narrative turn" of the post-modernists emphasise that our characters (such as The Working Class, Industrialisation, or Power) are significantly fictive.  We just don't create individuals out of whole cloth; our characterisations of the documentary record intend to be good, but the nature of writing (or speaking) means we can't live up to our hopeful standard completely.

Comment: @creative username - I know of a historical or legendary person who was described as "unknown".  The "Unknown Archon" who allegedly led the Serbs from White Serbia to Serbia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknown_Archon

Comment: You could also add *Pete Marsh* (a nickname often used affectionately for the bog body more commonly known as [Lidnow Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindow_Man)) and *Ginger*, (the name formerly given to the first of the [Gebelein predynastic mummies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebelein_predynastic_mummies) to be excavated, and who was still on display in the Egyptian Gallery at the British Museum the last time I visited) to your list.

Comment: Does anyone have insight into why the added details are not sufficient?

Comment: You might find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subaltern_Studies  interesting.

Comment: By providing examples (and credit to you for the research effort), haven't you answered the question yourself? (i.e. unknown persons are often named after where they were found or else some aspect of their appearance).

Comment: @LarsBosteen Sort of. I had hoped there was a broader term for the use of these "placeholder" names, or a term for the process of coming up with such names. For now it seems the topic is not so broad to warrant a 'catch all' term.